# TypeError: Cannot read property 'fnome' of undefined

Tags: node.js, express, backend, theory, body-parser

My level is lower than a beginner, so I'm pretty sure you will be able to help me and I hope you will.

I'm doing an exercise to learn back-end basics and I'm stuck on this "challenge".

I have to make a user type his name, last name and email... I tried in a way but got this mistake ("Cannot read property 'fnome' of undefined.") So I tried to console log the value of fnome to see but can't understand

Hope you will

Html code:

```
form action="/" class="form-signin" method="POST"  // Idk why but if i use html syntax it disappear


    <input type="text" name="fnome" class="form-control top" placeholder="First Name" required autofocus>

    <input type="text" name="surname" class="form-control middle" placeholder="Last Name" required>
    <input type="email" name="posta" class="form-control bottom" placeholder="Email" required>

    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign me up</button>
```

Back end part:

```
 const express=require("express");
 const http=require("http");
 const bodyParser=require("body-parser");

 const app=express();

 app.use(express.static("public"));
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

 app.get("/",function(req,res){
   res.sendFile(__dirname+"/index.html");
 });
 app.post("/",function(res,req){
   var name1=req.body.fnome;
   var cognome=req.body.surname;
   var mail=req.body.posta;
   console.log("name1,cognome, mail);

 });


 app.listen(3000,function(){
   console.log("Server is runing on 3000");
 });
```

P.S. I don't want to lie so I will admit that before writing here I checked the solution and it was correct, with the only difference that the teachers code was working my was plotting this mistake but the script was identical (with the only different chose of names)

Thank you and sorry for disturb

Comment: `(res,req)` should be `(req,res)` I guess.

Comment: You dont have any logic in the front name dealing with the fname. Nothing included, better check the original file, especially the react part (whichever front end you are using).

Comment: pzaenger thank you and sorry for having to see this shame ahahahah (y)

Comment: Thanks also to evrrybody else but i changed req and res and its working